# Correct option for handle MAX() when table is empty?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

When table is empty I guess all three perfomance is similar time. But not sure what will be the performance impact when table has million of records.

1 . Original query isnt affected, but dont like because have to make two separated db consults.

2 . Dont like because when no empty table have has to bring all the rows instead of using the index to find the max.

3 . Well this should return null instead of raising an error.

```
long? LastInsertedID;

try
{
  LastInsertedID = db.myTable.Any() ? 
                       db.myTable.Max(p => p.id) 
                     : 0;

  LastInsertedID = db.myTable.Select(p => p.id)
                             .DefaultIfEmpty(0)
                             .Max();

  LastInsertedID = db.myTable.Max(p => p.id); -- cause Exception
}
```

Exception:

> {"The cast to value type 'System.Int64' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type."}

Comment: What is the type of `id`? I thought it would throw a "sequence contains no items" exception

Comment: in db is not nullable long integer, but the problem is when db is empty.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IMO the working third option is the best. Database queries return `null` for most of the aggregate functions (except `COUNT`) when the set is empty, so is the suggestion by the exception message.

All you need is to include a cast to the corresponding nullable type:

```
LastInsertedID = db.myTable.Max(p => (long?)p.id);
```

Comment: Doh. I swear I try the duplicate question with this same suggestion and didnt even compile, even comment on it because tought was different lenguaje from C#. Now works perfect :/. TY

Answer (score 1):

The second is better. You avoid multiple database hits (or hits on the collection in general), it is clearer, and it can't fail.

Comment: But doesnt `SELECT` bring all the records from db to the Client and then calculate the `MAX` locally?

Comment: I don't think so, no. It's supposed to translate whatever it can into actual SQL. It may depend on your provider and its implementation.

Comment: run the sql profiler and check the generated query

Comment: Or you can do something like `context.Database.Log = x => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(x);`